# ng-bootstrap -> Typeahead Styling

Tags: angular, typeahead, ng-bootstrap

I seems to be unable to style the dropdown menu of the ng bootstrap typeahead.

Styles for the input itself is fine (the component only contains a input/typeahead) but nothing applies for the dropdown  (tried using the ngb-typeahead-window thatget inserted as well as the .dropdown-menu class for that.

Answer (score 5):

A great answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51417049/4248983

**tl;dr**

- The Typeahead window is a dynamically added component
- Your component implementing the Typeahead has styles encapsulated to only itself
- Set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in your `@Component` decorator to allow your component styles to be accessed globally

**WARNING**
Setting `ViewEncapsulation.None` will mean your component styles are available globally. *Ensure your css selectors are specific enough to prevent impacting other elements in your application!*

Answer (score 2):

ng-bootstrap is pretty limiting when it comes to changing its components. I'd say try using a [template](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples#template), that is the closest to customization you can come to. Plugins like ng-bootstrap and ngx-bootstrap are custom components that often don't support customizability to the extend that other plugins offer.

Comment: the template allow us make anything you want, why do you say is "pretty limiting"?

Comment: Curious. I mean css is  css, a selector is a selector?  Still nutting out Angular (coming from EmberJs), so maybe I missed something re. these component specific styleUrl's ?

Comment: Not sure. I can only logically guess that they use their own static styleUrls, because the styling is otherwise not changeable.

Comment: no offense, but kind of sound like you answered with limited knowledge of these widgets.