# ng-bootstrap - Typeahead dropdown width

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I started using the ng-bootstrap Typeahead component and I'm pretty happy with that.

One thing I would like to achieve is to get the dropdown items to have the same width as the input field, while the default behavior applies a width accordingly to the text length. It should be basic CSS...

I created a basic [Example](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/o9xs3zCUzm7YX6i6?preview) in Plunker.

As you can note, the applied style is ignored:

```
.dropdown-menu { width: 100%;}
```

While if I use browser dev tools, and apply the same it is applied.

Any idea on how to achieve the result, by using CSS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to the component

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-typeahead-template',
  templateUrl: 'src/typeahead-template.html',
  styleUrls: ['src/typeahead-template.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

See updated [plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/D9xusxuNJngT9Boy)

Without  ViewEncapsulation.None, the styles applied in this component will only effect this component and not any other component on this page.

Read [this](https://alligator.io/angular/viewencapsulation/) for more information

Comment: The problem of this approach is that the style is applied to every element matching in the whole application (as in style.css). Anything more scoped?

Comment: I am afraid there isnt any way of doing it. ngb-typeahead-window is the component added dynamically by the typeahead library and as I mentioned in the answer, the styles applied in the component(without encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None) will only effect this component and not any other component on this page or even inside the same component. For it to have effect outside the component, either include it globally in a css, or set encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None

Answer (score 8):

For me works ng-deep. Looks more safe and scoped:

```
::ng-deep .dropdown-menu { width: 100%; }
```

Comment: Worked for me as well

Answer (score 5):

This is how I made it work within responsive `col` :

```
::ng-deep ngb-typeahead-window.dropdown-menu {
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

or

```
::ng-deep .dropdown-menu.show {
    width:calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

Not sure which one is the best option but I tend to think of the first one.

Answer (score 1):

@Nandita's answer is correct, directly apply a width to dropdown menu won't affect.

And you want the dropdown menu to have same width as input, so you should add below CSS to her answer:

```
.dropdown-menu { width: 300px;}
```

Check result:
https://next.plnkr.co/edit/YvOymCLAwYgU3VmJ

Answer (score 1):

This code 100% work, but with the class `.dropdown-menu` any other dropdown will be changed

```css
::ng-deep .dropdown-menu { width: 100%; }
```

So I just used this code with `ngb-typeahead-` as the ID:

```css
::ng-deep [id^="ngb-typeahead-"]{ 
width: 100%!important; 
white-space: nowrap!important;
overflow: hidden!important;
text-overflow: ellipsis!important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Nandita Sharma's answer, when turning off ViewEncapsulation in Angular it's probably a good idea to scope any CSS rules to the component. This will avoid generically named classes from leaking out in the global CSS scope.

A really simple way of doing that is to scope everything inside of the component's selector:

```
// Name of the component containing the typeahead
app-parent-selector {
  // Rules added here won't leak out into the global CSS scope
  .dropdown-menu {
    width: 400px;
  }
}
```

It would also be wise to avoid any approach that uses shadow-piercing descendant combinators (::ng-deep, /deep/ or >>>) because support for them is gradually being removed from all major browsers and [will eventually be removed from Angular](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep).

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do would be adding this globally, provided you plan to use the type-ahead field the same way in all your pages. If you have a `styles.scss` which can hold all the global styles, add this there:

```
ngb-typeahead-window {
    width:calc(100% - 30px);

    .dropdown-item {
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using scss should do the trick. Find the parent **div** in your dom, and give it a class 'dropdown-wrapper'.

```
.dropdown-wrapper {
  .dropdown-menu {
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

Add this to your global scss. Cheers!